# GET data with foreign key from a SQLite database as nested JSON

Tags: python, json, sqlite, bottle

I am trying to GET data from a SQLite database as nested JSON.
I have two tables patient and journal. Journal has a foreign key to the CPR column in patients.
I have the bottle functions to GET the data:

```html
@get('/provider/pharmacy/cpr/<cpr>/token/<token>/JSON')
def _(token, cpr):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Mandatory.db')
        '''if limit == 0:
            raise Exception('Limit cannot be 0')'''
        if token not in users:
            raise Exception('Token is invalid')

        response.content_type = 'application/json'
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.row_factory = row_to_dict
        c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM patient JOIN journal ON patient.cpr = journal.patientcpr WHERE patient.cpr='{cpr}'")
        #c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM patient WHERE cpr in (SELECT date FROM journal WHERE patient_cpr='{cpr}')")
        result = c.fetchall()
        return json.dumps(result)

    except Exception as ex:
        response.status = 400
        return str(ex)
```

The result of this is:

```html
[
    {
        "id": "558211111",
        "name": "Oste pops",
        "cpr": 1122334421,
        "adress": "Peter parkervej99",
        "access": "*",
        "description": "Broken leg",
        "date_": "20/05/2022",
        "given_medicine": "Drugs",
        "patient_cpr": 1122334421
    }
]
```

but I would like it to be like this:

```html
[
    {
        "id": "558211111",
        "name": "Oste pops",
        "cpr": 1122334421,
        "adress": "Peter parkervej99",
        "access": "*",
        "journals":
        
        {
        "description": "Broken leg",
        "date_": "20/05/2022",
        "given_medicine": "Drugs",
        "patient_cpr": 1122334421
        }
    }
]
```

Is there some way this is possible?

Comment: Btw, there's an unrelated bug: your formal args are reversed. You wrote `def _(token, cpr):` but based on your route, it should be `def _(cpr, token):`.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Have you tried to code this yet? Try creating a journals dict, then assign the relevant keys to it and delete them from the parent dict. SQL and bottle seem irrelevant to this transformation so I'd leave them out of the question.